# Light Service Framework Fails to build if original readme followed

Tags: service, light, alljoyn

If we follow original readme for building LSF, its keep failing at the first step.

As soon as I run "scons" I get:

> scons: Reading SConscript files ... Checking c++ compiler support for
>   -std=c++11 flag... yes Using OpenSSL crypto GTEST_DIR not specified skipping common unit test build GTEST_DIR not specified skipping About
>   Service unit test build GTEST_DIR not specified skipping alljoyn_core
>   unit test build
>
> scons: warning: Ignoring missing SConscript
>   '/home/dms/lighting_alljoyn_poligon/base/config/cpp/SConscript' File
>   "/home/dms/lighting_alljoyn_poligon/core/service_framework/SConscript",
>   line 28, in  GTEST_DIR not specified skipping LSF unit test
>   build
>
> scons: warning: Ignoring missing SConscript
>   '/home/dms/lighting_alljoyn_poligon/core/ajtcl/SConscript' File
>   "/home/dms/lighting_alljoyn_poligon/core/service_framework/SConscript",
>   line 164, in  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no
>   attribute 'Append':  File
>   "/home/dms/lighting_alljoyn_poligon/core/service_framework/SConstruct",
>   line 5:    env.SConscript('SConscript')  File
>   "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 546:    return
>   _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 260:    exec *file*
>   in call_stack[-1].globals  File
>   "/home/dms/lighting_alljoyn_poligon/core/service_framework/SConscript",
>   line 166:    lamp_service_env.Append(LIBPATH = [
>   lamp_service_env.Dir('../ajtcl') ])

The warnings can be ignored, but at the bottom the append related issues are causing the stop of building process.

By the way I have built alljoyn framework including base services and it works perfect.

Any hint is welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the structure of the files.

The original SConsript file of LSF tries to access ../../base_tcl folder, but the base_tcl folder was located under services/ folder.

I have tried two solutions and both worked:
1. Either you change the path to the base_tcl folder in the SConscript
2. Or the folder base_tcl can moved to the proper path

I think this issue was caused because of version problem. The difference between 15.04 and 15.09